# No audio Input and Output Ubtutu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, headphones

My Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly stopped outputting audio and receiving input. Right now I can listen to audio if I use a bluetooth headphone, but neither "internal sound", nor usb headset are being recognized.

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux Lab 5.7.4-050704-generic #202006181331 SMP Thu Jun 18 13:33:57 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here's how Setting->Sound looks:
[image]

I've run this script after not being able to determine what's going wrong, i've seen that the snd-hda-intel module is definitely not loading.

```
wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && chmod +x ./alsa-info.sh && ./alsa-info.sh
```

The output is [here](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=e1a5df7319620e160070b4bb50cdba89110db411)

I've already tried reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio, didn't change anything :(

Edit: Adding more info

1. When I run `sudo lspci` the audio part is: `00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)`
2. My computer is a MSI GL62M-7RD

Edit 2: Adding the ouput of `aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and `pacmd list-cards`:

```
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf320000 irq 128"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a171"
        device.product.name = "CM238 HD Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  I thought I had no sound, but Bluetooth works here as well.  I have an Asus c436f Chromebook.  There is no way to run a virtual machine on Chomeos atm, so I loaded my go to 18.04.  It recognized none of the hardware.  20.04 recognized just enough to be usable. I tried all of the fixes for previous versions of Ubuntu with no joy.  What do you get when you run the command `sudo lspci` ?  I get much, but the prime candidate of that output is 00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8.
Looks like it will be a kernel issue based on my research.  I am on the latest as well.  Will keep you posted here if I find a resolution elsewhere.  What is your hardware platform?

Edit and FYI:
Mrchromebox who helped with defeating the uefi replied to this issue:

that's expected, it's just the built-in codec/amps (so speakers/mic) that aren't working. From a quick glance here, looks like the drivers are included, so probably just need the Alsa config/UCM/firmware from ChromeOS copied over. But I'd need to take a closer look

This may help you if you have not found it already.  Did not help me, but is rather comprehensive.  https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Comment: Added the requested info

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm not sure how the edit helps me exactly, it seems to be more of a Chrome OS centric fix